# Generate Random Number in 2D Array

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array, numbers

I am creating a game of Battleships using Java and I am having trouble generating 2 random numbers which randomly choose a place on the battleship board. For example, the computer has to randomly choose a space on the board to place the ships (and later to shoot on).

I have created a 2D array:

```
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;
char [][] grid;
grid = new char[rows][cols];
```

And then tried several different ways to get the two random numbers in the array but I cannot get it to work. Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
int randomPos = (char) (Math.random() * (grid[rows][cols] + 1));
```

Please ask me some questions if this doesn't make sense.

Sean

Comment: Is this for AI guessing locations to drop bombs? If so, you don't want duplicate locations, so it may be best to put all possible locations in a list then `java.util.Collections.shuffle(List)` them.

Comment: @Steve Taylor Yes, but I assumed I would have to do the same thing for choosing random positions for the computer to put their ships. What will that do?

Comment: Shuffling just rearranges the items in a list in a random order. Placing ships on the board is an entirely different matter. In that case, the easiest approach is brute force - just keep trying random locations and directions until a ship fits, repeating the same for all ships to be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random()` generates a decimal number. It doesn't make any sense to have square `3.5779789689689...` (or whatever you're referring to), so use the `Math.floor()` method, which rounds the number inside to the nearest integer. And as @Sanjay explained, generate the numbers separately...

```
int row = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
int col = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
```

Now you have actual integers that you can work with.

Comment: Is this instead of the 2D array? If not, how would I get the random numbers in the 2D array?

Comment: Yes, but if you need the array for something else don't delete it.

Comment: @Sean Just click the little checkmark under the up/down arrows in the upper left hand corner of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generate two random numbers separately and use them to index your board. To elaborate:

```
x = random(max_rows)
y = random(max_cols)
(x, y) -> random location (only if it's not already marked)
```

In your case, the range of the random number should be between 0 and 9 (inclusive both).

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomRow = Math.random() * grid.length;
int randomColumn = Math.random() * grid[0].length;
```

I wouldn't use char as my grid type, but the code above works all the same regardless of the types of in the array.

Comment: I had to use char so I could put a dash in set out the board. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this declare this is an ivar:

```
Random random = new Random();

//In the method do this:

int randomPos = generator.nextInt(11); //This generates a number between 0 and 10.
```